# Nuget package.targets not able to find files in copy task

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

**Background:** I have a library that's meant to be used with a C# game engine.  That game engine has an editor that picks up plugins via a `Plugins/` directory **of the project** (is not included in the build output).  In order to make life easy for users I want to package my library *and* the associated editor plugins packaged and deployed together in a single nuget file.  This way users don't have to manually manage the versions of two different sets of files.

**Problem:**

Nuget no longer has the ability to copy content files over by default.  Based on searching the only way to accomplish this is with tasks set up in an msbuild `package.targets` file.  So I have the following in my `csproj`

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="../Parme.Frb.Example/Plugins/**/*">
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <PackagePath>content\Plugins</PackagePath>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Parme.Frb.targets">
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <PackagePath>build</PackagePath>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

The `Parme.Frb.Example/Plugins` folder contains the plugin files I want to include in the nuget file.  My `Parme.Frb.targets` msbuild file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GluePluginFiles>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\Plugins\**\*</GluePluginFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="CopyGluePlugin" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(GluePluginFiles)" 
              DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)Plugins\%(GluePluginFiles.RecursiveDir)" 
              SkipUnchangedFiles="true"  />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The intention is that it will copy all files from the `<nuget-cache>/<package>/content/Plugins` directory and recursively copy it tho the project's `Plugins/` directory.

When I look at the built nuget file I see all the included content files
[image]

So I load this nuget file into a blank project and run a build, which produces the following errors:

```
Build started 4/12/2021 4:56:42 PM.
Logging verbosity is set to: Normal.     1>Project "C:\Users\me\RiderProjects\NugetTest\NugetTest\NugetTest.csproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
     1>C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\parme.frb\0.8.3-test10\build\Parme.Frb.targets(7,9): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\parme.frb\0.8.3-test10\build\..\content\Plugins\**\*" because it was not found.
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\me\RiderProjects\NugetTest\NugetTest\NugetTest.csproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "C:\Users\me\RiderProjects\NugetTest\NugetTest\NugetTest.csproj" (build target) (1) ->
       (CopyGluePlugin target) -> 
         C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\parme.frb\0.8.3-test10\build\Parme.Frb.targets(7,9): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\parme.frb\0.8.3-test10\build\..\content\Plugins\**\*" because it was not found.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.33
```

However, files most definitely do exist in this directory:

```
PS C:\Users\me> ls C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\parme.frb\0.8.3-test10\build\..\content\Plugins

    Directory: C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\parme.frb\0.8.3-test10\content\Plugins

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           4/12/2021  4:56 PM                Parme.Frb.GluePlugin
```

I've tried reorganizing the nuget package to remove the `..`, I've tried removing the `GluePlugins.` part of the `RecursiveDir` (which most tasks don't seem to have but that causes a different error`, etc..  I've tried a ton of stuff and can't get this to work.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can get this copying, without manually specifying each file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically why this works, but after a lot of trial and error I got it working via:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <GluePluginFile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\Plugins\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyGluePlugin" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
        <Message Importance="normal" Text="Copying Glue plugin files" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(GluePluginFile)"
              DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\Plugins\%(RecursiveDir)"
              SkipUnchangedFiles="true"  />
    </Target>
</Project>
```